# Markdown library isn't installed/urllib ImportError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, markdown

I'm trying to use Markdown with Django as shown in [this tutorial](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django). I've got the library installed and configured in Django using `django.contrib.markup`, but when I go to a page using markup, I get:

```
Error in 'markdown' filter: The Python markdown library isn't installed.
```

Then, through the interpreter I try running `import markdown`, which results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .treeprocessors import build_treeprocessors
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/treeprocessors.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import inlinepatterns
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markdown/inlinepatterns.py", line 47, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
ImportError: No module named parse
```

The Python documentation, however, tells me that `urlparse` has been renamed to `urllib.parse` in Python 3, which doesn't make any sense, because the Markdown library was installed through pip2, which put in into the python2.7 site-packages directory.

Changing that one line, by the way, results in more import errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how this happened, but reinstalling Markdown worked. In retrospect, I probably should have tried that first.